# RJS error: [object Error] in IE 8 on RJS response from rails/scriptaculous

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, scriptaculous, rjs

I have a controller with:

```
render :update do |page|
  page.replace_html 'some_id', :partial => 'some_partial'
end
```

It works fine in firefox, but IE throws an "RJS Error: [Object error]"

Looking at the generated javascript, it look like this:

```
Element.update("some_id", "\u003Cselect id=\"some_other_id\" name=\"some_name[]\"\u003E\u003Coption value=\"-1\"\u003E\u0026lt; Default option \u0026gt;\u003C/option\u003E\n\u003Coption value=\"1\" selected=\"selected\"\u003E Some option \u003C/option\u003E\u003C/select\u003E\n");
```

But even trying with `Element.update("some_id", "hello world")` fails in IE.
Replacing with an empty string works, though.

Looking into the Element.update function:

```
update: function(element, content) {
  element = $(element);
  if (content && content.toElement) content = content.toElement();
  if (Object.isElement(content)) return element.update().insert(content);
  content = Object.toHTML(content);
  element.innerHTML = content.stripScripts();
  content.evalScripts.bind(content).defer();
  return element;
}
```

It seems that `element.innerHTML = content.stripScripts();` is causing some trouble, throwing an "Unknown runtime error" no matter what I feed it, except the empty string.

I know that IE will complain if trying to put a block-level element inside an inline element, but this is not the case.

I'm on rails 2.3.11, scriptaculous 1.8.1 and prototype 1.6.0.3

I'm quite lost - any hints is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `page.replace` instead of `page.replace_html`. It looks like you may be updating a select lists options with another select list. Another way would be to just replace the options using `options_for_select` to render the options tags.

Comment: I already tried working with `page.replace`, but that will replace the entire `some_id` tag and not just its innerHTML.

But your idea with `options_for_select` works like a charm! :-)

`page.replace_html 'inner_id', options_for_select(collection, selected)`

No idea why, must be the "IE magic fail syndrome"...

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify - Using `replace_html` updated the select list to look like this: `<select><select>[…options…]</select></select>` Replacing the options of the current select with a select tag and its options. I guess IE doesn't like that markup but other browsers are more forgiving. Good to see you got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of element is "some_id"? I was trying to update the contents of a "p" element, and it just wouldn't work. I switched the "p" to a "div" and it worked fine. All other browsers, IE9, ff, chrome, etc, etc worked, but not IE8 and below.